# Why are the TX+ and TX- pins on my laptop's Ethernet port shorted?

Tags: microcontroller, ethernet, rs485, network

I understand that these are supposed to be differential signals with a resistance equal to the characteristic impedance of the cabling between them. However, using a multimeter to check the continuity between pins (1, 2), (3, 6), (4, 5) and (7, 8) gives me a 100% short. The multimeter progressively settles down to a resistance of 0 Ω.

I was wondering if the short-circuit happens because of the coil of the "magnetics" circuit used inside the connector, but after removing the connector, the pins are again shorted on the board. I'm baffled. Does this mean that if I externally short these pins, the connection will still work?

[image: Ethernet]

I'm struggling to understand how differential signaling works on a circuit level. Any excellent resources for beginners is much appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Transformer on the input between each pair. For DC (multimeter), a coil will read as zero Ω.

[image]
Image from: https://www.pulseelectronics.com/1gigabit-magnetic-modules-small-footprints-that-packs-a-punch/

Comment: I will add a comment to expand on this answer.  The "characteristic impedance" is not the same as DC resistance.  At the operating frequency, the transformer will pass the signal to the diff pair on the secondary side it.  DC does not get passed through.  At frequency, the diff pair will appear to have an impedance of approx 100 ohms.  This sort of measurement can be made using a VNA.

Comment: Okay! Is the transformer supposed to be on the circuit or inside the RJ45 connector?

Comment: Most probably straight behind the RJ45 on the  motherboard.